# How to Use Both Google Drive Android API and REST API

Tags: google-drive-android-api

This is a similar issue as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49568796/com-google-android-gms-common-api-apiexception-17-api-drive-api-connectionles), but I have confirmed a slightly different phenomenon from that.

There are two types of APIs to access GoogleDrive, the Android API, and the Google Drive REST API, but ApiException 17 occurs only when using the Android API.

I tried creating a new Google Account and running it, it worked fine and I was able to create a holder on GoogleDrive.

But curiously, after that, if you use Method using Google Drive REST API with the same account, This Exception 17 occurred again in the method using the Android API, and it became impossible to solve anything afterward.

Further. Trying to access the holder created with the Android API with the REST API will cause a UserRecoverableAuthIOException to be recovered from here.

The problem is that there is no way to recover Exception 17 that occurs when accessing with Android API after accessing with REST API. (It may be because I have not found it.)

Anyone, who knows how to recover in this case?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: The only way I figured out how to do it was by using the mGoogleSignInClient.revokeAccess(); and then again creating the sign in client with the new Android API.